# Node.js - Styles doesn't apply to page & Google Chrome says: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-type

I began studying node.js and stuck at the beginning. I was trying to solve this problem several times but no succeed. I was googling, stackoverflowing and found problems like mine. But not exactly or solutions doesn't work for me. Please, help me!

I have simple **index.html** file with following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>SimpleApp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/default.css" />
</head>
<body>

  Hello, Node!
  <script src="js/application.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is simple server in **server.js** file:

```
var http = require('http');
var mime = require('mime');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  fs.readFile('./index.html', function(error, data) {
    if(error) {
      response.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type' : 'text/html'});
      response.end('<h1>File <index.html> not found.</h1>');
    } else {
      var contentType = undefined;
      if(request.url === '/') {
        contentType = 'text/html';
      } else {
        contentType = mime.lookup(request.url);
      }
      response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : contentType});
      response.end(data);
    }
  });
});

server.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('Server started.');
})
```

After I start server - styles doesn't apply to page & Google Chrome says: **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**.
I know problem inside **fs.readFile** callback,inside **else**, but what?

Comment: What did you expect? You're serving the same file (`index.html`) to *every* request.

Comment: Here is what server says: text/html text/css application/javascript image/x-icon? Or i don't understand something?!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (need to be refactored):

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var mime = require('mime');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  var filePath = undefined;
  var contentType = undefined;

  switch(request.url) {
    case '/':
      filePath = './index.html';
      contentType = 'text/html';
      break;
    case '/styles/default.css':
      filePath = './styles/default.css';
      contentType = mime.lookup(request.url);
      break;
    case '/js/application.js':
      filePath = './js/application.js';
      contentType = mime.lookup(request.url);
      break;
    default:
      filePath = request.url;
      contentType = mime.lookup(request.url);
  }

  fs.readFile(filePath, function(error, data) {
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type' : contentType});
    response.end(data);
  });
});

server.listen(8000, function() {
  console.log('Server started.');
});
```